# Converting a list to a list of dictionary references

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of strings:

```
listofdictrefs = ["ws['D4']", "ws['H72']", "ws['B4']"]
```

Those strings are actually dictionary references. I want to convert that list to variable references so I can write those variables to a csv line:

```
csvwriter.writerow(listofdictrefs)
```

Right now, of course, it writes the list as strings. I python to know to reference the variables (in this case dictionary entry) that matches that name.

Comment: If you aren't concerned about security you can use `csvwriter.writerow(eval(x) for x in listofdictrefs)` but [be careful](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).  Further I would use `eval(x, None, ws)` for at least some protection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ws` is the actual name of the dictionary variable then you can write it out using `eval`s, though this is error-prone.  Even in a situation where you're not dealing with untrusted input (so, let's say security concerns aside) You're pushing the syntactic and a lot of the semantic analysis to runtime when it could be checked statically.  nonetheless:

```
csvwriter.writerow(eval(r) for r in listofdictrefs)
```

However, if possible you'd be better off keeping a list of keys and indexing the `ws` dict

```
keys = ['D4', 'H72', 'B4']
csvwriter.writerow(ws[k] for k in keys)
```

`eval` is rarely the right solution.

Comment: I didn't knew the eval() function. One can always learn something new every day. Thanks :D

Comment: @Meowtwo117 handle with extreme care, if you are calling `eval` on **anything** where you don't trust the contents (anything coming from a file or user or other input source) it isn't safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` in this situation.  Always be careful of running unchecked code with `eval`, though!

```
listofdictrefs = ["ws['D4']", "ws['H72']", "ws['B4']"]
ws = {'D4' : 100,'H72' : 50,'B4' : 25}
for ref in listofdictrefs:
    print eval(ref)
```

```
100
50
25
```

Comment: `eval` is pretty dangerous and should only be used as a last resort. If this list is generated via user input what do you think would happen if this string was in the list: `'__import__("subprocess").call("rm -rf ~")'`?

Comment: I agree, hence my warning.